# Geting bike paths coordinates from Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

**Introduction:**
Google Maps allows to show a bicycling route on the map from point X to point Y. Google can also show all bike paths on given map with 4 different types: Trails, Dedicated lanes, Bicycly-friendly roads, Dirt/unpaved trails. The different bike paths are painted with different colours.

**What I need to do:**
I need to write an application that will (when given start point X, and endpoint Y) retrieve information of how big percentage of the 4 types of bike paths does the route contain, so the result should be like that, ex.
Trails: 20%
Dedicated lanes: 15%
Bicycly-friendly roads: 40%
Dirt/unpaved trails: 25%

**Is that possible to fetch such information from Google Maps API?**

**My research:** 
I have figured out that there is a BicyclingLayer object (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-bicycling) which allows to paint bike paths on the map, and the documentation says that this bicycling layer is painted on the map by the DirectionsRenderer when BICYCLING is chosen as a travelMode. I have actually tested that I can show the bicycling paths on my map. I wonder if it is possible to get the coordinates of the bike paths from the Google Map (after they got painted), or maybe is it possible to get them direction for the BicyclingLayer after it is displayed on the map?

If I can somehow get the coordinates of all the bike paths painted, then I can calculate the percentage of 4 types of paths that my route consists of.

Any help on that, and a sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't seem to find that information in the `directionsService` response. You might want to submit a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list).

Comment: I have added a feature request here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7392&thanks=7392&ts=1417026265. Hope they will introduce such a feature in a future version. For now the only option I have is to scrape the data from Google Maps site...